# jBPM 6.2 assign Human Task to group

Tags: jboss, jbpm, bpmn

I'm creating Process with User Task with following code:

```java
public void transformToNode(
        final RuleFlowProcessFactory factory) {
    factory.humanTaskNode(
            getId())
            .taskName(getType())
            .name(getName())
            .actorId(getActors())
            .done();
}
```

But I want to change direct user assignment to group assignment, so it would be easier to manage resources in the future.
So how can I assign HumanTask to a group and add users to that group?

Answer (score 0):

I see a method under that factory for 'swimlane' which should correspond to the task group.

Comment: Could you provide some sample, please?